# QWidget raise above matplotlib canvas

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, matplotlib, pyqt, qt5

I am working on a project on which I have a GUI (coded by hand) with two tabs, and on each tab I have a different canvas (to plot different things in each tabs).
But, I added also some widgets on these tabs and when I add them to the layout, if I add the canvas at the same position of a button in the layout for example, I can click on this button anymore.
I know on PyQt it is possible to raise the level of the widget, so is there a way to do the same thing with a canvas?

Thank you in advance for your help. On this example, the "Quit" is active only on the right half.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

class FenetrePrincipale(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FenetrePrincipale, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    # Fonction de configuration de la classe
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.Form = Form

        Form.setMinimumSize(1220, 850)

        self.creation_GUI()
        self.creation_figure()
        self.creation_layout()

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.Bouton_quitter.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 60))

    def creation_GUI(self):
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()

        self.Widget_choixPalette_Label = QLabel(self.tab1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_Label.setText("Text1")
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox = QComboBox(self.tab1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.addItem("Try1")
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.addItem("Try2")

        self.Bouton_quitter = QPushButton(self.tab1)
        self.Bouton_quitter.setText("Quit")

    def creation_layout(self):
        LayoutForm = QGridLayout(self.Form)
        LayoutG1 = QGridLayout()
        LayoutTab1 = QGridLayout(self.tab1)
        WidgetTemp = QWidget()
        LayoutWidgetTemp = QGridLayout()

        LayoutG1.addWidget(self.Bouton_quitter, 21, 29, 1, 2, Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        LayoutG1.addWidget(self.canvas, 2, 10, 20, 20)

        LayoutWidgetTemp.addWidget(self.Widget_choixPalette_Label, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        LayoutWidgetTemp.addWidget(self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        WidgetTemp.setLayout(LayoutWidgetTemp)
        LayoutG1.addWidget(WidgetTemp, 1, 18, 2, 4)

        LayoutTab1.addLayout(LayoutG1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "  Tab1  ")

        LayoutForm.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)

    def creation_figure(self):
        # Create figure (transparent background)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.figure.patch.set_facecolor('None')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")

        # Adding one subplot for image
        self.axe0 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axe0.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axe0.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        plt.tight_layout()

        # Data for init image
        self.imageInit = [[255] * 320 for i in range(240)]
        self.imageInit[0][0] = 0

        # Init image and add colorbar
        self.image = self.axe0.imshow(self.imageInit, interpolation='none')
        divider = make_axes_locatable(self.axe0)
        cax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.05, pack_start=True)
        self.colorbar = self.figure.add_axes(cax)
        self.figure.colorbar(self.image, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')

        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))
    form = FenetrePrincipale()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- Operating system: windows 7 Pro
- Matplotlib version: 4.0.4
- Matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg
- Python version: 3.6
- Other libraries: PyQt5

Edit 25/10/17 : new code for example

Comment: Why are you trying to add two widgets at the same position? That is never going to work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is because the figure don't take all the space of the canvas, so I want to optimize the space adding my button where the figure is not.

Comment: The correct way to deal with this is to remove the empty area at the top of the canvas. Maybe try: `plt.tight_layout()`.

Comment: No change with this command :( Unfortunately. I will try to add the canvas and others widgets in two different layouts now but it is sad not to find solution to this.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example that shows how to get a canvas with that empty space at the top? I cannot find a way to reproduce that. If I could, I might be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: I edited my original post with an example on which I add a ComboBox above the figure (with a new QWidget in layout so it is okay) and a "Quit" Button under which is add to the same layout as the figure. If you place your cursor on this button, you'll see that on the right half of the button, you can interact with the button because it is "outside" the figure place, and on the left half you can't interact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a version of your example script that fixes all the issues. Most of the problems are caused by a very muddled use of layouts. I had to completely
re-write the `creation_layout` method in order to get a sane starting point so I could see where the problems were. I also temporarily restored the background colour of the canvas to make it easier to see how the widgets are layed out relative to each other. I realize that it won't be easy to incorporate some of my changes into your real code. But hopefully it will give you some ideas on how to simplify your layout structure.

The most important fix is the use of [subplots_adjust](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) in the `creation_figure` method. This removes all the empty space at the top of the canvas, so there is no longer any need to try to position other widgets on top of it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

class FenetrePrincipale(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FenetrePrincipale, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    # Fonction de configuration de la classe
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.Form = Form

        Form.setMinimumSize(1220, 850)

        self.creation_GUI()
        self.creation_figure()
        self.creation_layout()

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.Bouton_quitter.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 60))

    def creation_GUI(self):
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "  Tab1  ")

        self.Widget_choixPalette_Label = QLabel(self.tab1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_Label.setText("Text1")
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox = QComboBox(self.tab1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.addItem("Try1")
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.addItem("Try2")

        self.Bouton_quitter = QPushButton(self.tab1)
        self.Bouton_quitter.setText("Quit")

    def creation_layout(self):
        LayoutForm = QGridLayout(self)
        LayoutForm.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        LayoutTab1 = QGridLayout(self.tab1)

        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.Widget_choixPalette_Label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.setMinimumWidth(200)

        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.canvas, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.Bouton_quitter, 2, 3, 1, 1, Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

        LayoutTab1.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        LayoutTab1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        LayoutTab1.setColumnStretch(2, 1)

    def creation_figure(self):
        # Create figure (transparent background)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        # self.figure.patch.set_facecolor('None')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")

        # Adding one subplot for image
        self.axe0 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axe0.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axe0.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        # plt.tight_layout()

        # Data for init image
        self.imageInit = [[255] * 320 for i in range(240)]
        self.imageInit[0][0] = 0

        # Init image and add colorbar
        self.image = self.axe0.imshow(self.imageInit, interpolation='none')
        divider = make_axes_locatable(self.axe0)
        cax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.05, pack_start=True)
        self.colorbar = self.figure.add_axes(cax)
        self.figure.colorbar(self.image, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0.05, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)

        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))
    form = FenetrePrincipale()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer ! I admit my `creation_layout`method is quite messy but here is a small example from my real GUI which have around 30 widgets on it. Next time I will use QtDesigner because someone show me how to promote widget for external widget as canvas is. 

I will look also the `stretch` because I don't know what it is ^^

Comment: Thank you so much ! Between the methods `subplots_adjust` and `addColumnStretch` I didn't know, it is so much confortable to create layout by hand !

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin. Yes, I was going to suggest using Qt Designer with widget promotion, but I suppose it might be a lot of work to convert your existing code. In the long run, It would make your life a lot easier, though.

Comment: Yes next time I will do this. I am still discovering the Qt World which is just outsized !

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the order you add things to the layout. Add the canvas first, then the button on top

```
    LayoutForm.addWidget(canvas,1,0,1,6)
    LayoutForm.addWidget(button,1,0,1,2)
```

Comment: It is not working with my real code. I do the same thing with 5 widgets:
`LayoutG2.addWidget(canvas2, 1, 10, 21, 20)`
`LayoutG2.addWidget(Widget_choixPalette_2_Label, 0, 11, 1, 4)`
`LayoutG2.addWidget(Widget_choixPalette_2_ComboBox, 1, 11, 1, 4)`
`LayoutG2.addWidget(Widget_imageSelectionnee_Label, 0, 15, 1, 3)`
`LayoutG2.addWidget(Widget_imageSelectionnee_Edit, 1, 15, 1, 3)`
`LayoutG2.addWidget(slide, 1, 18, 1, 5)`
But I can interact only with the slide, not the QEdit or QPushButton. Maybe I miss something else?

I have multiple layout on my GUI (because I have tabs) for info.

Comment: If you don't have the plotting, can you interact with the rest of the objects? If yes, add them to a layout, and position the layout above the canvas

Comment: I'll try to add widgets in two different layouts and come back.

Comment: It is ok with different layouts for information, thanks. But I try again to find a solution without this workaround ^^